# Give reference to string parameters in outer class method Android

Tags: android

I am calling some function of outer class from my activity and I want to give reference of parameters so that I can get updated value.

I m calling function like this:

**My activity:**

```
String var1;
ArrayList<String> var2;

OuterClass outerClass = new Outerclass();
outerClass.someMethod(var1, var2);
```

**My outer Class function:**

```
public void someMethod(String var1,ArrayList<String> var2) {
// after some operations 
var1 = "somevale1";
var2 also have some value;
```

I need to access both of updated value in my activity without any return statement only from reference. But here I am getting error `variable accessed from within inner class needs to be declare final` but I cannot declare final.

What should I do to give reference just like TextView and EditText?

Comment: Hi Spartan, after calling the outerClass.someMethod(var1,var2); did you check what the values of var1 and var2 are ?

Comment: after you call the outerClass.someMethod(var1,var2); if you just try to print var1 and var2, you can see the changes gets applied to them, values will be the changed values. If that is not your requirement, please can you expand on your question, where are you getting 'variable accessed from within inner class needs to be declare final', reply with these details so that we can help. I am also eager to know who upvoted the question, when you declare ArrayList<String,String> java throws compile time error saying 'Wrong number of type arguments'.

Comment: I am getting error and without resolve that error I can run project?

Comment: Put the outer Class inside your main activity class. Make the variable global and remove the parameters in the method already

Comment: @Sheychan I want to reuse the code that is why I am putting code outside activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare as global variables and make them final.

```
final String var1;
final Arraylist<String> var2;
```

Comment: If you declare as global, you cannot declare final without assigning values. If you declare global variables as final without assigning values, it gives compile time error. Moreover in the outerclass.someMethod(), the var1 and var2 are being modified, so that's the reason why the OP says he cannot declare final.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Take a bean class, and put it into var1, var2 and then update in out class method and that updated values reflected into that bean object.

```
class CustomBean{
    String var1;
    ArrayList<String> var2;
}

OuterClass outerClass = new Outerclass();
outerClass.someMethod(Bean bean);

public void someMethod(String var1,ArrayList<String> var2) {
  // after some operations 
  bean.var1 = "somevale1";
  bean.var2 also have some value;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have ArrayList<String,String> read question properly, it is giving him compile time error.

Comment: @sravan see here Arraylist not ArrayList.

Comment: There is only ArrayList, there is nothing like Arraylist, that I guess is just a typo by the OP.

Comment: @sravan i guessed Arraylist<String, String> is custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update values in such way, because you pass to method just references to where date is stored. What I suggest is change signature of your method, so it returns:

```
return new Pair<String, ArrayList<String>> (var1, var2);
```

Krishna's answer is also correct, but I see no real need in such architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somethink like this. The signature of someMethod was changed.

```
public class SOActivity extends Activity 
{
    private String var1;
    private ArrayList<String> var2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();
        outerClass.someMethod(this);

        android.util.Log.d("SOActivity", "var1=" + var1);
        android.util.Log.d("SOActivity", "var2=" + var2.get(0) + var2.get(1));
    }

    public void setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    public void setVar2(ArrayList<String> var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }
}

public class OuterClass {
    public void someMethod(SOActivity soActivity) {
        // Some big init for var1 and var2
        soActivity.setVar1("somevalue1");

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("My");
        al.add("solution");
        soActivity.setVar2(al);
    }
}
```